RMarkdown - Knit to PDF
I am new to R programming. I have downloaded the packäge tinytex() using install.packages("tinytex") successfully. However, I cannot install this package using "tinytex::install_tinytex()". I am getting an error (screenshot below). Can anyone advise please?

I have tried restating R Studio and downloading the tinytex package many time and still receiving the same error message.

Please don't use images for code, error messages, etc. See here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557

this appears to be a network issue, have you tried again since?

yes. its working fine now - thank you
